# How to make this function pointfree without making the code harder to read?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have written this function:

```
-- Either exact match or is suffix of ".example.com" (mind the dot)
-- This prevents for overlapping like "myexample.com"
isDomainOf :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString -> Bool
isDomainOf a b = (a == b) || a `B.isSuffixOf` (B.append "." b)
```

If I apply [pointless](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree#Tool_support) to the function I get:

```
isDomainOf = ap (ap . ((||) .) . (==)) ((. B.append ".") . B.isSuffixOf)
```

Which is obviously even longer and harder to read than the pointful version.

The problem is the or operator, because I can't just write the left and right hand sides of `(||)` like this:

```
isDomainOf = (==) || (. append ".") . isSuffixOf
```

Is there any better way to express this?

Comment: Why does it need to be pointfree?  Only make things pointfree if it improves readability.

Comment: @bheklilr It doesn't have to be, I was just wondering if there was a more readable piontfree version of my function.

Comment: Probably not without writing some helper functions, which defeats the purpose in my opinion.  You could turn those `ap`s into `<*>` and make them infix, but I don't know how much that'll really improve readability.

Comment: I don't want to be a downer here, but this doesn't look much like a function that can be easily made point-free, in particular because of the `B.append "." b` part, which just ruins the symmetry.  Otherwise you would be much more likely to end up with a readable point-free form.

Comment: Replacing `B.append "." b` with just `b`, you could re-write it as `isDomainOf a = (||) <$> (a==) <*> (B.isSuffixOf a)`, which isn't too bad, but I think the point-full form is much more readable still.

Comment: Pointful it is, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general scheme is that you have

```
foo :: A -> B -> C    -- foo = (==)                           :: BStr->BStr->Bool
bar :: A -> B -> D    -- bar = (\a b -> a`isSuffixOf`(':':b)) :: BStr->BStr->Bool
comb :: C -> D -> E   -- comb = (||)                          :: Bool->Bool->Bool
```

and want to express `\a b -> comb (foo a b) (bar a b)`. First of course it's a good idea [to hoogle for that specific combinator](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+d%29+-%3E+%28c+-%3E+d+-%3E+e%29+-%3E+a-%3Eb-%3Ee+%2Bpointless-fun), but it's a bit too crazy for this to expect results.

To try making a point-free version ourselves (as bheklir remarks, it's probably a bad idea here to consider that in the first place), first observe it becomes much easier when the infixes aren't curried.

```
foo' :: (A,B) -> C
bar' :: (A,B) -> D
```

why, if you then unify `(A,B) ~ P`, we simply need to put `foo'` and `bar'` in parallel and feed the results to `comb`. With the `Arrow` combinators, this looks thus:

```
        uncurry comb . (foo' &&& bar')
```

which isn't too bad. Of course, writing out all with the necessary uncurrying makes it nevertheless a nightmare to read:

```
   curry $ uncurry (||) . (uncurry(==) &&& \(a,b) -> a`isSuffixOf`(':':b))
```

Since we still have a lambda in there, it's still not point-free anyway; though that one can of course be unpointed as well:

```
   curry $ uncurry (||) . (uncurry(==) &&& uncurry(((':':).) . isSuffixOf))
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me to understand why it is a bad idea.